# How can I select an option from my multi-select box and update my chart?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am working with html,css, jquery etc. for the first time. I have successfully implemented a multi-select drop down. I want my multi-select to update my chart.
Example: If i click du and li in my multi-select dropdown, the chart should show only those values and legends. I should not be able to see Mrd.
Here is my code :

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type:'line',
    data : {

    labels: [10,20,30,40,50,60],
    datasets : [{
      label:'Du',
      data:[
        3,
        6,
        10,
        12,
        19,
        25
      ],
      backgroundColor:'pink',
      borderWidth:4,
      borderColor:'#777',
      hoverBorderWidth:3,
      hoverBorderColor:'#000'

    },{
      label:'Lt',
      data:[
        14,
        28,
        80,
        20,
        60,
        45
      ],
      backgroundColor:'yellow',
      borderWidth:4,
      birderColor:'black',
      hoverBorderWidth:3,
      hoverBorderColor:'#000'

    },{
      label:'Mrd',
      data:[
        16,
        18,
        28,
        45,
        60,
        80
        ],
      backgroundColor:'orange',
      borderWidth:4,
      birderColor:'black',
      hoverBorderWidth:3,
      hoverBorderColor:'#000'

    }],

    },
    options:{
      title:{
        display:true,
        text:'Defects',
        fontSize:15
      },
      legend:{
        position:'bottom',
        labels:{
          fontColor:'red'
        }

    },
      layout:{
        padding:{
          left:50,
          right:0,
          top:0,
          bottom:0
        }
      },
      tooltips:{
        enabled:true
      }
    }
});
$('#dataset').on('change', function(){
  if(this.value=="1"){
   myChart.data.datasets[0].data=[   3,
                              6,
                              10,
                              12,
                              19,
                              25]
   myChart.data.datasets[1].data = $('dataset').empty();
   myChart.data.datasets[2].data = [16,
                              18,
                              28,
                              45,
                              60,
                              80],
    myChart.update();
  }else if(this.value=="2"){
    myChart.data.datasets[0].data = $('dataset').empty();
    myChart.data.datasets[1].data = [ 14,
                            28,
                            80,
                            20,
                            60,
                            45];
    myChart.data.datasets[2].data = [   16,
                            18,
                            28,
                            45,
                            60,
                            80

    ]

    myChart.update();
  }else if(this.value=="3"){
    myChart.data.datasets[0].data=[3,
                            6,
                            10,
                            12,
                            19,
                            25];
    myChart.data.datasets[1].data=[14,
                            28,
                            80,
                            20,
                            60,
                            45];
        myChart.data.datasets[2].data = $('dataset').empty();

    myChart.update();
  }
});
$('#langOpt').multiselect({
  columns:1,
  placeholder:'Select Defects'
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>
        Defect Charts
    </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- JS & CSS library of MultiSelect plugin -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
    <script src="multiselect/jquery.multiselect.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="multiselect/jquery.multiselect.css">
  </head>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="form-group mt-3 mb-3">
        <label for="dataset">Select Factor</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="dataset">
          <option id="opt1" value="1">Low</option>
          <option id="opt2" value="2">Medium</option>
          <option id="opt3" value="3">High</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-4"></div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col-8">
      <div id="chart-wrapper">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <h4>Multi-Select Defect</h4>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4"></div>
          <select name="langOpt[]" multiple id="langOpt">
            <option value ="Du">Dust</option>
            <option value ="Lt">Lint</option>
            <option value ="Mrd">Manual Rundown</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you made a very nice job there.

I was adding the below code to your code.

```
$('.multiselect-container.dropdown-menu').on('change', function(){
  var selectedDefect = $('.multiselect-container.dropdown-menu > li.active');
  if(selectedDefect.length > 0){
    selectedDefect.each(function(){
      console.log($(this).find('input').val());
    });
  }

});
```

So with what I put into the console.log, you should be able to filter as you made it earlier in your JS the data you wish to show or not. So you would need to save selected value from your other selected and hten filter them.

You will also need to add else after my if to make sure that when there is no li with class="active" it shows the whole graph.

If you wish I can continue but from here you should be able to catch up based on what you made.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type:'line',
    data : {

    labels: [10,20,30,40,50,60],
    datasets : [{
      label:'Du',
      data:[
        3,
        6,
        10,
        12,
        19,
        25
      ],
      backgroundColor:'pink',
      borderWidth:4,
      borderColor:'#777',
      hoverBorderWidth:3,
      hoverBorderColor:'#000'

    },{
      label:'Lt',
      data:[
        14,
        28,
        80,
        20,
        60,
        45
      ],
      backgroundColor:'yellow',
      borderWidth:4,
      birderColor:'black',
      hoverBorderWidth:3,
      hoverBorderColor:'#000'

    },{
      label:'Mrd',
      data:[
        16,
        18,
        28,
        45,
        60,
        80
        ],
      backgroundColor:'orange',
      borderWidth:4,
      birderColor:'black',
      hoverBorderWidth:3,
      hoverBorderColor:'#000'

    }],

    },
    options:{
      title:{
        display:true,
        text:'Defects',
        fontSize:15
      },
      legend:{
        position:'bottom',
        labels:{
          fontColor:'red'
        }

    },
      layout:{
        padding:{
          left:50,
          right:0,
          top:0,
          bottom:0
        }
      },
      tooltips:{
        enabled:true
      }
    }
});

$('#dataset').on('change', function(){

  var selectedDefect = $('.multiselect-container.dropdown-menu > li.active');
  if(selectedDefect.length > 0){
      var defect = false;
      var defect2 = false;
      var defect3 = false;
    selectedDefect.each(function(){
      
      if($(this).find('input').val() == "Du"){
        defect = true;
      }
      if($(this).find('input').val() == "Lt"){
        defect2 = true;
      }
      if($(this).find('input').val() == "Mrd"){
        defect3 = true;
      }
    });
      
      dataSet2($('#dataset').val(), defect, defect2, defect3);
    } else{
      dataSet($('#dataset').val());
    }
  
  // This will add a selected attribute on the option you choose
  $("#dataset").val(this.value)
  .find("option[value=" + this.value +"]").attr('selected', true);
  
});

$('#langOpt').multiselect({
  columns:1,
  placeholder:'Select Defects'
});

$('.multiselect-container.dropdown-menu').on('change', function(){
  var selectedDefect = $('.multiselect-container.dropdown-menu > li.active');
  var factorSelected = 1; //Set basicly Low
  if($('#dataset > option:selected').length > 0){
    factorSelected = $('#dataset > option:selected').val();
  }
  
  if(selectedDefect.length > 0){
      var defect = false;
      var defect2 = false;
      var defect3 = false;
    selectedDefect.each(function(){
      if($(this).find('input').val() == "Du"){
        defect = true;
      }
      if($(this).find('input').val() == "Lt"){
        defect2 = true;
      }
      if($(this).find('input').val() == "Mrd"){
        defect3 = true;
      }
    });
    
    dataSet2(factorSelected, defect, defect2, defect3);
    //console.log($(this).find('input').val());
    
  }
  else{
    dataSet(factorSelected);
  }

});

function dataSet2(event, defect, defect2, defect3){
  if(event=="1"){
    if(defect === true){
      myChart.data.datasets[0].data=[3,
                                    6,
                                    10,
                                    12,
                                    19,
                                    25]
    }
    else if(defect === false){
      myChart.data.datasets[0].data = $('dataset').empty();
    }
    if(defect2 === true){
      myChart.data.datasets[1].data = $('dataset').empty();
    }else if(defect2 === false){
      myChart.data.datasets[1].data = $('dataset').empty();
    }
    if(defect3 === true){
      myChart.data.datasets[2].data = [16,
                                      18,
                                      28,
                                      45,
                                      60,
                                      80]
    }else if(defect3 === false){
      myChart.data.datasets[2].data = $('dataset').empty();
    }
    myChart.update();
  }else if(event=="2"){
    if(defect === true){
      myChart.data.datasets[0].data = $('dataset').empty();
    } else if(defect === false){
      myChart.data.datasets[0].data = $('dataset').empty();
    }
    if(defect2 === true){
      myChart.data.datasets[1].data = [ 14,
                              28,
                              80,
                              20,
                              60,
                              45];
    } else if(defect2 === false){
      myChart.data.datasets[1].data = $('dataset').empty();
    }
    if(defect3 === true){
      myChart.data.datasets[2].data = [   16,
                              18,
                              28,
                              45,
                              60,
                              80

      ]
    } else if(defect3 === false){
      myChart.data.datasets[2].data = $('dataset').empty();
    }
    myChart.update();
  }else if(event=="3"){
    if(defect === true){
    myChart.data.datasets[0].data=[3,
                            6,
                            10,
                            12,
                            19,
                            25];
    }else if(defect === false){
      myChart.data.datasets[0].data = $('dataset').empty();
    }
    if(defect2 === true){
      myChart.data.datasets[1].data=[14,
                              28,
                              80,
                              20,
                              60,
                              45];
    }else if(defect2 === false){
      myChart.data.datasets[1].data = $('dataset').empty();
    }
    if(defect3 === true){
      myChart.data.datasets[2].data = $('dataset').empty();
    }
    else if(defect3 === false){
      myChart.data.datasets[2].data = $('dataset').empty();
    }
    myChart.update();
  }
}

function dataSet(event){
  if(event=="1"){
   myChart.data.datasets[0].data=[   3,
                              6,
                              10,
                              12,
                              19,
                              25]
   myChart.data.datasets[1].data = $('dataset').empty();
   myChart.data.datasets[2].data = [16,
                              18,
                              28,
                              45,
                              60,
                              80],
    myChart.update();
  }else if(event=="2"){
    myChart.data.datasets[0].data = $('dataset').empty();
    myChart.data.datasets[1].data = [ 14,
                            28,
                            80,
                            20,
                            60,
                            45];
    myChart.data.datasets[2].data = [   16,
                            18,
                            28,
                            45,
                            60,
                            80

    ]

    myChart.update();
  }else if(event=="3"){
    myChart.data.datasets[0].data=[3,
                            6,
                            10,
                            12,
                            19,
                            25];
    myChart.data.datasets[1].data=[14,
                            28,
                            80,
                            20,
                            60,
                            45];
        myChart.data.datasets[2].data = $('dataset').empty();

    myChart.update();
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>
        Defect Charts
    </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- JS & CSS library of MultiSelect plugin -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
    <script src="multiselect/jquery.multiselect.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="multiselect/jquery.multiselect.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
          <div class="form-group mt-3 mb-3">
            <label for="dataset">Select Factor</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="dataset">
              <option id="opt1" value="1">Low</option>
              <option id="opt2" value="2">Medium</option>
              <option id="opt3" value="3">High</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4"></div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col"></div>
        <div class="col-8">
          <div id="chart-wrapper">
            <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
          </div>
          <div class="container">
            <h4>Multi-Select Defect</h4>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-4"></div>
              <select name="langOpt[]" multiple id="langOpt">
                <option value ="Du">Dust</option>
                <option value ="Lt">Lint</option>
                <option value ="Mrd">Manual Rundown</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please let me know the else part too? I am unable to grasp it :/

Comment: @tiredcoder Ok The else is done I also set your filter that that was checking the value to his function like this I could use it in the on.change you created and in the else I added. If I would be you I would create a similar function with 2 variables (one variable by select)

Comment: @tiredcoder Normaly it is done now the whole stuff :-) dont forget to mark your question solved. Btw, there is no body element to your html. Bye

Comment: @MaxiGui hey MaxiGui I accidentally rejected your suggested edit on my Safari Bug question (I mis-read your edit), you can re-submit it if you want and I'll approve. I don't know how to undo my rejection so I'm just letting you know here

Comment: @MaxiGui Thanks a lot. I am unable to see the "else" part.. Can you edit the answer?

Comment: They are the answer. Dont you see `else{
      dataSet($('#dataset').val());
    }` and `else{
    dataSet(factorSelected);
  } ` depending on which element is changing. But did you try the filtering?

Comment: @tiredcoder I can give you more explication about what I made, if you wish